# How to toggle simple_form_for visibility using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

I have `simple_form` form.

```
.row
  .span12
    %legend='Address Data'
    = f.simple_fields_for :person do |p|
      = render 'profiles/contact_type/address_form', f: p
.row
  .span12
    %legend='Email Data'
    = f.simple_fields_for :person do |p|
      = render 'profiles/contact_type/email_form', f: p
```

I would like to toggle each subform visibility.

Right now I am using:

```
= link_to_function 'Address data', '$("#addresses").toggle();'
```

But I think this is not the best option. How should I do this?

Comment: You want to toggle them all together ? If they all have a common class, use `$(".commonClass").toggle();`

Comment: Toggle is deprecated.

Comment: No, I want to toggle them one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally like jQuery's toggleCLass.
Something like this should work (not tested).

The Javascript (in coffee)

```
jQuery ->  
    $(document).on "click", '.i_toggle_my_next_sibling', ->
        $(this).next().toggleClass( "visibility_hidden", 400, "easeOutSine" )
```

The HTML (you want to use your simple_form notation):

```
<div class="i_toggle_my_next_sibling">Toggle Control</div>

<div>
    My most beautiful content to show and hide ...
</div>
```

Some css

```
.visibility_hidden {
    visibility:hidden;
 }
```